# how to send "" instead of null in select * statement SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM specifications
```

I want to send "" or "0" instead of null[if any column having null value],

can't use column-wise, more than 80 columns

Comment: Use `coalesce()`, more than 80 times.

Comment: "can't use column-wise" you want to say "I do not want to use..." because this is all you can.

Comment: You can use Coalesce,Is Null or IfNull

Comment: *can't use column-wise, more than 80 columns* This really means "I'm too lazy for to write over 80 separate expressions" - but it is the only way for to solve your problem.

Comment: ISNULL OR IFNULL will work as column-wise ,
ISNULL(specifications.*,"") will not work
how to use Coalesce

Comment: You mean like `SELECT COALESCE(all 80 columns) FROM specifications`? Or maybe `SELECT CONCAT(all 80 columns where IFNULL(column,0)) FROM specifications`? Or just `SELECT IFNULL(column1), IFNULL(column2) ... IFNULL(column80) FROM specifications`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the only way is to use `COALESCE()` OR `ISNULL()` as many times as the count *(80)* of your columns.

Just to make it easier, you can use the below query to generate that 80 statements for you.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ISNULL(',COLUMN_NAME ,',' , 
                (CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE ='int' THEN '0' 
                      WHEN DATA_TYPE ='varchar' THEN '' ELSE '' END) , ')' ) 
       AS DERIVED_COLUMN
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'specifications'
```

[**CHECK SAMPLE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39795e02da905f3c0b6601e4f7694589)

*Note : This is under the assumption that all your column are of `int` or `varchar` datatype. If you have other datatypes, modify the `CASE` accordingly.*